# Cannot auto configure pydev in eclipse

Tags: eclipse-plugin, pydev

I have installed PyDev successfully, I have python 3.4.0 installed successfully and the folder containing python.exe is in my path and I can run it from the command line.

However, when I go to window\preferences\pydev\interpreters\python interpreter and select 'quick auto-config' to configure it using normal python I get an error saying 'auto configurator could not find a valid interpreter... Note the system environment variables used for Jython are PATH and PYTHONHOME.'

Unless this is a bug in the text I am not selecting Jython (I get a different error if I select IronPython, btw, so this is not a generic error message).

The trace is as follows:

Errors getting info on discovered interpreter(s).
See error log for details.

java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "python": CreateProcess error=2, The system cannot find the file specified

As I say, python.exe is in my path.

Answer (score 4):

You have to install the actual python package separately from here https://www.python.org/download

Close LiClipse/Eclipse => Download Python Here: https://www.python.org/download

=> reopen LiClipse => Auto Config for the interpreter Will WORK!

Comment: It did go 1 step further, but then I got the same error again with different details: Errors getting info on discovered interpreter(s).
See error log for details.
  java.lang.RuntimeException: No output was in the standard output when
trying to create the interpreter info for: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
The error output contains:>>Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
<<
  java.lang.RuntimeException: No output was in the standard output...

Comment: ... when
trying to create the interpreter info for: C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
The error output contains:>>Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.
<< [so this pop-up window seems to contain 2 copies of the same error text twice. Above it it says that "PATH" and "PYTHONHOME / PYTHON_HOME" environment variables are used when auto-searching for a Jython interpreter although I unticked Jython & IronJython]

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, but I'll leave this up in case anyone else gets it. It's a pretty stupid auto config option if you ask me ;)

In the higher level window\preferences\pydev\interpreters\ preference you need to untick jython and ironpython.

No idea why given I selected the Python sub-preference specifically.

Comment: It seems like a bug... can you report that at https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/ ?

Comment: "Notify when a Jython project has no interpreter", and similarly for IronPython. I still got the same error with slightly different "Details". Then I had to manually add the python interpreter path and name:
C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311
python.exe
(Note: I have LiClipse, not Eclipse)